# How to use Azure Media Service live streaming in webpage

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I connect the live streaming using Azure Media Service And also i have created one channel in azure. They have provided one Ingest URL for me.

How can i use this URL in my website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you get astreaming manifest (generally ends in .ism/manifest) you can use Azure Media Player to play it back. Check out the documentation [here](http://aka.ms/ampdocs) and you can test out the url in our demo page [here](http:////aka.ms/azuremediaplayer)